# What happens if iOS images sizes are not rightly calculated?

Tags: ios

What happens if I will have an 1x image at 100x100, the 2x image at 190x190 and the 3x image at 290x290? Will it make any difference?

I used [Slender](http://martiancraft.com/products/slender.html) to analyse the images in my project and it flooded me with several warnings saying the image sizes are not right and the dimensions are a mismatch.

Comment: Unless these images are for icons, nothing will happen image will be little distorted.

Comment: Please feel free to leave a comment on why you do not like the question :)

Comment: There are few things you must learn buddy 1. Because I commented does not mean I down voted (for your knowledge I din down vote)  2. There is nothing to ask in this question hence you have recieved downvotes if you have image set and see in proper device you will see the output for your self  3. People here in SO are helping you by answering not doing their duty so be polite when u ask for help :)

Comment: Didn't target you with that comment Sandeep. I was talking in general. Besides, you had commented already :)

Comment: And I am sorry if I did not sound polite. It never was the intention ;)

Comment: Thats ok I sounded rude too sorry :) Hope you now have your answer as Lion has already answerred your query :)

Answer (score 0):

5 or 10 pixels doesn't make major difference when image size is 200 or 300 pixel. But, you should follow the standard(as per apple guideline) that 2x should be double and 3x should be triple of 1x respectively.

Comment: If you not follow standard then you'll definitely got warnings

Comment: Ahh Ok... makes sense